# Iterate over two lists, one list could be empty

Tags: python

I'd like to get the product of two lists. I can do this using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

for i in product([1, 2], ['a', 'b']):
    print(i, end='\t')
```

Gives:

```
(1, 'a')    (1, 'b')    (2, 'a')    (2, 'b')
```

The problem is that one of the two lists could be empty. I just need to iterate over the non-empty list as a normal for loop in this case. Something like:

```py
for i in something([1, 2], []):
    print(i, end='\t')
```

To give:

```
1    2
```

The code works fine if I handle the exception at the beginning with many `if` statements that checks for the lengths of the lists, and with the same code for every combination (`list1` is empty, `list2` is empty, none are empty), but this way I just wrote the same code 3 times:

```py
from itertools import product

if not list1:
    for i in list2:
        print(i, end='\t')

elif not list2:
    for i in list1:
        print(i, end='\t')

else:    
    for i in product(list1, list2):
        print(i, end='\t')
```

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: cant you just loop over a tuple? `for i in (lst, lst2):`

Comment: @Tomerikoo that doesn't solve the " In the second case I need all of the combinations, like a nested for loop", sice the zip_longest prints all the elements of the longer list, but it doesn't combine them with the elements in the shorter. It just mark them as "None"

Comment: @The.B I need to access both elements since they are columns in dataframe which I need to select with a .loc separately

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think that it's pretty clear, but anyway:
`list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ["a", "b"]
out = 1 a, 1 b, 2 a, 2 b, etc`

Instead if one list is empty:
` list1 = []
list2 = ["a", "b"]
out = "a", "b" `

Comment: Checked for product, I think it doesn't work if one list is empty. If they are the same lenght I just need the combination like a nested loop

Comment: "The problem is that one of the two lists could be empty. I just need to iterate over the non-empty list as a normal for loop in this case." This design doesn't make any sense. `Special cases aren't special enough`. That said, I'm unmarking the duplicate because that's clearly not the same question - iterating in parallel won't help here.

Comment: Anyway, one way to avoid some of the repetition with this code (just please consider using a different sentinel value, perhaps `None`) is to determine what you're iterating over first, and then unconditionally do the iteration over that thing. But beyond that the question doesn't really make sense; if you want things to work in different ways conditionally, you're going to need to do some kind of work to test the condition.

Comment: Well, it closed with a duplicate link, which is no good. Apparently my reopening cleared the other close votes too. :/

Comment: @Federicofkt `list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2 if len(lst2) > 0 else " "))` this will work if your first list is always bigger than the second. but you can put it in a if statement to check wich `list` have the bigger length.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you the following approach:

```
seq = product(list1, list2) if (list1 and list2) else (list1 or list2)

for item in seq:
    print(item, end='\t')
```

You can read about [Logical operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612144/logical-operators-in-python) to understand why the use of `and` and `or` works.