# Python - understanding of the array limit algorithm and Lambda functions

Tags: python, algorithm, lambda

I have this code that returns limited list or array as we want
but I'm feeling some lack in learning this algorithm.
as we know this function will return True for min or max If they are not specified.
but my question is

if we want limit(arr,max=7) without minimum
then we will have a True and a Number in our IF STATEMENT (in return section of function)

what that is mean in Python? a True and a Number,
What about a True and a None?
Thanks For Your Helping

```
# code
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

def limit(arr,min=None,max=None):
    min_check = lambda var: True if min is None else var>=min
    max_check = lambda var: True if max is None else var<=max

    return sorted([x for x in arr if min_check(x) and max_check(x)])

print(limit(arr,min=2,max=7))
```

Comment: Both `min_check` and `max_check` always return booleans. `True`, `var>=min` and `var<=max` are all always boolean.

Comment: I know that. that is not my question. my question is if we have Number && True in an if statement , what that means in python.

Comment: For that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612144/logical-operators-in-python

Comment: To be clear though, when you say *"if we want limit(arr,max=7) without minimum then we will have a True and a Number in our if statement (in return section of function)"* - that isn't right for this code. Nothing in this code can ever result in `True and <number>` being evaluated, because `min_check` and `max_check` always return booleans.

Comment: Don't define named functions with lambda expressions. Use `def min_check(var): return min is None or var >= min` instead.

Comment: It make sense now . thanks bro :)